# Compare objects and export the difference

Tags: powershell, select-object

I would like to make a script that compares O365 tenant settings. Reading them is fine, now I would like to make some kind of difference object. 
A related question is here, but no answer.
[Powershell Compare-Object and getting the Differences into a File](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30628041/powershell-compare-object-and-getting-the-differences-into-a-file)

I already have a json file from both tenants created like:

```
$srcTenant | Select-Object -Property * | ConvertTo-Json | Out-File "$targetfolder\$targetfile"
```

Now, I would like a file that only contains the properties that are collected with the script below:

I am so far:

```
$properties = ($srcTenant | Get-Member -MemberType Property | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name)
$selectedproperties = @{}
$i = 0
foreach ($property in $properties) {
  if (Compare-Object $srcTenant $trgTenant -Property "$property") {
  $selectedproperties.Add($i, "$property")
  $i++
  }
}
```

The $selectedproperties variable contains 9 properties and I would like to export only this 9 in the same format as the other two.

Name                           Value
----                           -----
8                              StorageQuotaAllocated
7                              StorageQuota
6                              ResourceQuotaAllocated
5                              ResourceQuota
4                              OwnerAnonymousNotification
3                              OneDriveStorageQuota
2                              DefaultLinkPermission
1                              ConditionalAccessPolicy
0                              AllowDownloadingNonWebViewableFiles

So, I am looking for something like:

```
$srcTenant | Select-Object -Property (that 9 property above) | ConvertTo-Json | Out-File "$targetfolder\$targetfile
```

Other options achieving the same result are welcome too :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Select-Object -Property` can take an array of property names.

see the [first example here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/getting-started/cookbooks/selecting-parts-of-objects--select-object-?view=powershell-6)

Comment: How would I pass the properties as array? I am not really familiar with this area of PS.

Comment: @vilmarci - something like `select-object -Property $selectedproperties.values` would work for this situation. [This page](https://kevinmarquette.github.io/2018-10-15-Powershell-arrays-Everything-you-wanted-to-know) is a good intro to powershell arrays.

Comment: Thanks, `$selectedproperties.values` didn't work, but the solution was using an array instead of the hashtable. I switched to that and now it works :)